# How to retrieve primary key value of selected row through JDBC (mariaDB)

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I have a problem getting the primary key value of a selected record with JDBC.
I have HashMap with the table name as key and the primary key name as value and I'm iterating through it in order to find the table name the user has selected and get the primary key name. Up to that point everything works fine but when I try to get the primary key value it always returns 0.

The server I'm using is running on MariaDB 2.4.1 and I'm using Java 1.8. Below is the for loop responsible for the match of the user input and the assignment of the primary key name. Inside the try catch statement I try to get the primary key value but it returns always 0. The primary key is set in the database as auto incrementing and the value updates normally in the database.

```
for (Map.Entry hashMap : getTablesWithPrimaryKeys().entrySet()) {
    if (getTableName().compareTo(hashMap.getKey().toString()) == 0) {
        setPrimaryKey((String)hashMap.getValue());
        System.out.println(getPrimaryKey());

        try {
            PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM " + tableName, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            statement.executeQuery();
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.getGeneratedKeys();

            if (resultSet.next()) {
                setPrimaryKeyValue(resultSet.getLong(1));
                System.out.println(getPrimaryKeyValue());
            }

            connection.close();
        } catch (SQLException exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not getting an exceptions thrown so there is something that I'm missing for sure here. Any help please?

Comment: Your query is `select * from ...`, and you always get the first column value as a long: `resultSet.getLong(1)`. You never use the primary key column name anywhere. Note that the whole point of a map if to get the value based on a key. Iterating through the entry defeats the whole point.

Comment: Also, a select statement won't generate new keys, so I fail to see the point of `RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS`

Comment: And finally, selecting all the rows and all the columns of each row of a table just to get one row's primary key value is not the most efficient thing to do.

Comment: As @JB says, `getGeneratedKeys` is for retrieving the key value(s) generated by an INSERT statement, so calling it after executing a SELECT statement doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: So, it seems that I got it a bit wrong. How should I go about getting the primary key value of a selected row when I know the primary key column name?

Comment: `select <the_column_name> from <the_table> where ...`?

Comment: This is the part I'm getting stuck. ..."where" +  getPrimaryKey + "=" .....what? This is why I wanted to get the primary key value of the selected row.

Comment: If you already know the value of the primary key, what's the point of getting it from the database? What are you trying to achieve? What concrete problem are you trying to solve? What is a "selected row"?

Comment: I don't know the value of the primary key, I just know the primary key column name. What I'm trying to achieve with this is to have a java program that can dynamically connect to an SQL database and let the user manage tables, records etc.

Comment: Yeah, but that's way too vague. What is this specific piece of code supposed to do?

Comment: The user is selecting a table name and this piece of code is trying to match the table name with a key in the HashMap. This key has the column name of the primary key as value so the only piece missing now is the value of the primary key which I want to get dynamically.

Comment: A table usually has many, many rows. If you know the table name (let's say 'customer') and the name of the primary key column name for this table (let's say 'customer_id'), every row of the table will have a different value for this column: 1, 2, 3, ..., 78297468. So, based on this example, what should your method do?

Comment: Well what you described is the situation I'm currently in. I populate a JavaFX tableview with data from my database. The user can then select a row from that table view and view the details in another scene. The reason I want to get the primary key value is in order to display the image of the selected row. This piece of code should give me the primary key value in order to use it later when displaying the image.

Comment: So the problem is a purely logical one. If the user selects a row **in a JavaFX tableview**, then you'll find the primary key of the selected row **in the JavaFX tableview**. Not in the database table, which has no idea of which row you selected in your Java application. Use your JavaFX tableview to find the selected row, and extract the primary key value from there.

Comment: Thanks for your time and help. I'm quite new to stack overflow so I don't know if this question will be helpfull to others. If you think it will though, post your answer and I will upvote it.

Comment: You can delete it.